# How to display text over responsive image by css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 4 columns in which I have images with different sizes followed by a absolutely positioned mask, appearing on hover.

The width of mask exceeds the images

How can I set the mask always the same width as the width of the image?

https://jsfiddle.net/tsjzrmra/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap"><div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-4">
     <div class="show show-first">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100X200" />
        <div class="mask">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-4">
     <div class="show show-first">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120X200" />
        <div class="mask">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-4">
     <div class="show show-first">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150X200" />
        <div class="mask">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-4">
     <div class="show show-first">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/180X200" />
        <div class="mask">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {  box-sizing: border-box; }
.wrap{
  width: 87%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #eee;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; 
}
[class*='col-']{
  float:left;   
}
.col-1-3{
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 20px;
} 
.col-2-3{
  width: 66.66%; 
  padding: 20px;
}
.col-1-4{
  width: 25%; 
  padding: 10px;
}
.show{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.show .mask{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
.show-first .mask {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.show-first:hover .mask {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .col-1-4{
    width: 50%; 
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: right;
  }
  .wrap{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .mobile-clear{
    clear:both;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could make image as your background for the mask.

Comment: Actually what is your expected result?

Comment: @ketan i want like this http://screencast.com/t/3Otwt6iA mask in full width of image

Comment: Then you should give width to image. Is it ok if width 100% ?

Comment: Because it is unknown  for use to know with using css

Comment: @ketan image can't be width: 100%; only max-width: 100%; so i need responsive image for small resolution and max width for large resolution

Comment: Then i think you should use scripting language. like Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

You may simply remove this definition:

```
width: 100%;
```

and edit this one

```
display: block;
```

into

```
display: inline-block
```

for `<div class="show">`. Also if you want the `<div class="show">`s to have center aligned, you need to add

```
text-align: center;
```

to `<div class="col-1-4">`.

## In action:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap{
  width: 87%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #eee;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
[class*='col-']{
  float:left;   
}
.col-1-3{
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 20px;
}
.col-2-3{
  width: 66.66%; 
  padding: 20px;
}
.col-1-4{
  width: 25%; 
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.show{
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.show .mask{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
.show-first .mask {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.show-first:hover .mask {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
  .col-1-4{
    width: 50%; 
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: right;
  }
  .wrap{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .mobile-clear{
    clear:both;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="show show-first">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100X200" />
      <div class="mask">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="show show-first">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120X200" />
      <div class="mask">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="show show-first">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150X200" />
      <div class="mask">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="show show-first">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/180X200" />
      
      <div class="mask">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Only one last question before i marked this answer, i see in bottom of class `show` some spacing space, how can i remove it? if i add for class `mask` next `.show .mask { height: calc(100% - 5px); }` it will be work in other browsers? http://screencast.com/t/uaxjUoFN9

Comment: That is because display property of that `img` are as `inline`. you may simply add `vertical-align: bottom;` to style definitions for the `img`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a div wrapper around the content:

```
<div class="show show-first">
  <div class="mask-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100X200" />

    <div class="mask">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi sequi laboriosam delectus ipsa, vel nulla ipsum quod esse molestias nam quos eius. Reprehenderit repellat atque voluptas autem velit, distinctio esse.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then update the CSS

```
.mask-wrapper: {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.show {
  text-align: center;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%; // it's better to change it into a class instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this script,

```
 $('.show').hover(function(){
   var getimg = $(this).find('img').width();
    //alert(getimg);
     $('.mask').css({'width':getimg})

  });
```

Try this [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXQONo)

Comment: The OP is after a CSS solution. there is no JS tag on the question. Please note to the tags in future.